# Errors in converting LaTeX using ToExpression

Tags: latex, conversion

I am trying to write a function which takes Maple Latex generated, feed it to Mathematica, use `ToExpression` then convert it back to Latex.

This is because Mathematica Latex generated is a much better quality than Maple's.

For some latex, it works with no problem.

For some other I tried, it did not work. Mathematica gives lots of `ErrorBox` and `Null` in the translated Latex and I do not know why, since the Maple Latex is valid and can be compiled using tex with no problem.

Here is an example of a Latex string (I include this Latex in a plain text file with link at the bottom to make it easy to reproduce the problem)

```
\begin{align*}
p &=  \frac{  \partial G}{\partial x}+ \frac{  \partial G}{\partial \
p} \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\\ 
p -  \frac{  \partial G}{\partial x}&= \frac{  \partial G}{\partial \
p} \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\tag{3A}
\end{align*}
```

\begin{align*}
p &=  \frac{  \partial G}{\partial x}+ \frac{  \partial G}{\partial \
p} \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\\ 
p -  \frac{  \partial G}{\partial x}&= \frac{  \partial G}{\partial \
p} \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}}\tag{3A}
\end{align*}

Now when  using the command

```
 TeXForm[ToExpression[str , TeXForm, HoldForm]]
```

Mathematica gives this

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  \text{TI}(p)  &  \left\{\text{ErrorBox}[\text{ErrorBox}[=]],\text{Null},\frac{\partial G}{\partial
   x},\text{Null},\text{ErrorBox}[\text{ErrorBox}[+]],\text{Null},\frac{\partial G}{\partial p},\text{Null},\frac{d p}{d x}\right\}  \\
  \left\{p,\text{Null},\text{ErrorBox}[\text{ErrorBox}[-]],\text{Null},\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}\right\}  & 
   \left\{\text{ErrorBox}[\text{ErrorBox}[=]],\text{Null},\frac{\partial G}{\partial p},\text{Null},\frac{d p}{d x},\text{Null},3 A\right\}  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I will show the code below on how to reproduce the above.

Getting the Latex from Maple to Mathematica was a little tricky. Maple saves the latex to a plain text file called "input.txt" and Mathematica reads the Latex from this file.

I found that using `ReadString["input.txt"]` does not work, as Mathematica for some reason adds an extra new line between each line in the file and this break the latex.

So I am now using the following method instead:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]] (*where input.txt is located*)
str = "";
line = ReadLine["input.txt"];
If[line =!= EndOfFile,
  While[line =!= EndOfFile,
   str = str <> line;
   line = ReadLine["input.txt"];
   If[ line =!= EndOfFile, str = str <> "\n"]
   ]];
```

Now `str` above has the latex code as string. Next

```
 TeXForm[ToExpression[str , TeXForm, HoldForm]]
```

And that is where the problem shows up.

This is the  file [input.txt](https://www.12000.org/tmp/073119/input.txt)

Any idea why Mathematica does not produce good Latex for this and if there is a workaround? I am not going to use the `Expression` generated from Maple latex in any way, other than to convert it to Latex again, so I can use the Mathematica Latex instead of the Maple Latex.

The other thing I am not sure about is this: If the Latex input is *valid*, is Mathematica expected to always handle `ToExpression[str , TeXForm, HoldForm]` with no issue at all? Or it not necessarily so? Are there limitations on what the Latex can contain then?

Comment: The extra lines are likely to to be `\r\n`, in which case:  `string = ReadString[f]; If[string === EndOfFile, string = ""]; StringReplace[string, "\r\n" -> "\n"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, Mathematica seems to parse the equations fine (aside from trying to multiply the lines together), but doesn't understand the `\begin{align*}`. I would guess that since it's called `TeXForm`, it can parse TeX primitives but not all LaTeX macros (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267980/what-is-a-primitive-a-macro-and-how-do-they-compare) for the difference), unless they are macros generated ass the output of `TeXForm`. Indeed, `\def` does work, but not any of the non-math LaTeX commands I tried.

```
s1 = "p &=  \\frac{  \\partial G}{\\partial x}+ \\frac{  \\partial G}{\\partial p} \\frac{  \\mathop{\\mathrm{d}p}}{\\mathop{\\mathrm{d}x}}\\\\ 
p -  \\frac{  \\partial G}{\\partial x}&= \\frac{  \\partial G}{\\partial p} \\frac{  \\mathop{\\mathrm{d}p}}{\\mathop{\\mathrm{d}x}}\\tag{3A}"

s2 = "\\begin{align*}
1+1
\\end{align*}"

s3 = "\\def \\surround [#1][#2]{#1 + #2 + #1}
\\surround[1][2]"

Echo[ToExpression[#, TeXForm, HoldForm]]& /@ {s1, s2, s3}

(*
>> HoldForm[(p == D[G, {x}] + D[G, {p}]*(d*p)/(d*x))*(p - D[G, {x}] == D[G, {p}]*(d*p)/(d*x)*3*A)]
>> HoldForm[ExpressionCell[TraditionalForm[{{TextCell[Row[{ , ExpressionCell[{1, Null, ErrorBox[ErrorBox[+]], Null, 1}, InlineFormula],  }]]}}]]]
>> HoldForm[1 + 2 + 1]
*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZDBasQgEIbvPsWwwh6alKI5L3QP2/YB9lDQHGx0k0CiolkIyDx7qixleyi0lw44/I4f8/84q2Uws1rGTm1bZHCAnYf9AUDKS1BdKsKrsIxqgldM98uK1a@Mx@9IdhmcTzcR5qTRI6af5iuizAXEw@NfkuS8/xplUX1qjrgjJPLyQ1J@mH60SU1jbx@QsIoRKY3VX5NCNjdSm0s2jNcQ3NVqEJS1gvI2UQYVUF4aQ3InRH7nbV5w6gYnzu60@mBiHJ0VtIazeX9xYa7hzU26qLbdw9MzpMhqiDyfBrftEw)

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) also hints through omission that `ToExpression` with `TeXForm` is mainly useful in inverting `ToString[#, TeXForm]&` in the first place, as the only two examples dealing with `ToExpression`.

> Use ToExpression to convert TeX back to Wolfram Language syntax: [...]
>
> Use ToExpression to convert from TeX to the Wolfram Language: [...]

Even the `ExportString` example, which generates a full LaTeX document, cannot be inverted by `ToExpression`.